# Build Android NDK Project in Windows

Tags: android, eclipse, makefile, android-ndk, cygwin

I know, it sounds crazy, but I want do it.
Also I want possible running and debugging my project in Eclipse!!! 
(I know, I completely mad man)

I install Android NDK, Cygwin (with "make"), add to path "C:\cygwin\bin;C:\Art\android-ndk\"
and did some other actions. If I run Project on Eclipse, I recieve error message:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project FFWall ****

bash C:\Art\android-ndk\ndk-build V=1 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
ERROR: Your GNUMAKE variable is defined to an invalid name: /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/make
Please fix it to point to a valid make executable (e.g. /usr/bin/make)

**** Build Finished ****
```

I spent 5 days simply to start the project. But at me it turns out nothing. prompt please, what I do not so and with what the above-stated mistake is connected?

Comment: Do you really have make executable in C:\Cygwin\bin folder?

Comment: make -v GNU Make 3.82.90

Comment: You do not have to use Cygwin to build and debug Android NDK projects. There's a Windows version of the NDK available from Google and it contains executables that can be run directly in Windows.

Comment: You can answer in more detail?

Comment: Just run ndk-build.cmd bat file from folder where you have AndroidManifest.xml file. It will automatically parse jni/Android.mk file and build everything without cygwin.

Comment: Interesting error. It looks like `android-ndk\ndk-build` tries to resolve what is the actual location for make. I would try the following: (1) try to set windows `%PATH%` to contain `C:\Cygwin\bin` (2) try to run `GNUMAKE=/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/make ndk-build V=1` (3) run `bash -X ndk-build` and try to find out what happens from output.